# Random world generation of streets

Tags: algorithm, random, language-agnostic, terrain

I am trying to randomly generate terrain for a game, in such a way that an object at position `x, y` is of type number `f(x, y)` (so I don't have to store the values of all the objects. I am trying to generate an environment like a city, with streets and blocks between them.

For example:

```
# # # # #   # # #   # # # # 
# # # # #   # # #   # # # # 
# # # # #   # # #   # # # # 
# # # # #   # # #   # # # #
# # # # #
# # # # #   # # # # #   # # 
            # # # # #   # # 
# # # # #   # # # # #   # #  
# # # # #   # # # # #   # # 

#   # # # # # # #   # # # # 
#   # # # # # # #   # # # # 
#   # # # # # # #   # # # # 
#   # # # # # # #   # # # #
```

I can generate something kind of like this in a regular pattern, using `f(x, y): (x*y) mod n`, where `n` is a constant and a resulting tile is only empty if `f(x, y) == 0`.

For instance, with `n` as 5:

```
# # # #   # # # #   # # # # 
# # # #   # # # #   # # # # 
# # # #   # # # #   # # # # 
# # # #   # # # #   # # # # 

# # # #   # # # #   # # # # 
# # # #   # # # #   # # # # 
# # # #   # # # #   # # # # 
# # # #   # # # #   # # # # 

# # # #   # # # #   # # # # 
# # # #   # # # #   # # # # 
# # # #   # # # #   # # # # 
# # # #   # # # #   # # # #
```

How can I alter my algorithm (or get a new one) to get results more like the first example?

Or am I going about this completely the wrong way?

Comment: Search for rogue-like dungeon generators. You should be able to adapt one to your needs. Just replace rooms->building and hallways->roads and you're done.

Comment: @Geobits Will those work as I want, with a function? As I could create an algorithm that builds a map up bit by bit to be like this, but then it would have to be all stored in memory, wouldn't it?

Comment: No structures in memory at all? Can I ask why? If you want to draw this to the screen, you're not going to want to run `f(x,y)` for every pixel/block on each screen refresh.

Comment: @Geobits Sorry, I should've probably given context. The whole world will be very large - too large to store in memory - so I currently intend to periodically put the area around the player by generating it from `f(x, y)`, and then (part) of that. Should I just store the world in a file, and load parts of it as necessary instead?

Comment: Or you could store the *seed* of each area used to "randomly" generate it. When a character enters an area, just regenerate that area and store the local objects in memory. Again, like rogue-likes do(the ones that let you save progress, anyway).

Comment: @Geobits So would I generate each area in a different way (involving calls to the random function) but store the seed for each area, then generate it it again on the fly based on that seed? Or would I make a deterministic algorithm for each area, based on a seed, and store that seed (and if so, what algorithm could I use for that)?

Comment: There are many algorithms. It all depends on what you want it to look like. That's why I recommend a good search term(rogue-like) for them.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is [Perlin Noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise).

Comment: @Geobits So as I understand it, I use an algorithm to make each section of the map, based on a seed, and save the seed. Then when I want to use the area again I regenerate it based on the seed. Are there any easy ways to link the areas together?

Comment: Yes, but it's a pretty broad topic. There are entire books about how to procedurally generate worlds, and several websites with examples and tutorials. SO, however, isn't one of them.

Comment: @Geobits Thanks, I will start implementing it like that, however I will still leave this question open, as the function here seems to be very close, and I'd be interested to see if there is a way to change it to do what I want.

Comment: @mbeckish How would I use Perlin noise in this way? I know that it can be used to generate random height maps etc., but in this case the texture that I want to generate is different - there are effectively only two different "colours" that I want to use, and I want a relatively regular pattern of lines.

Comment: @user2387370 - You could set a threshold value to clamp the pixel values to 0 or 1.  But you're right - this would generate organic looking paths, not orthogonal paths.

Comment: Geobits gave the best suggestion - the rogue-like dungeon generators will do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a function that produces more or less what I want, however it could definitely be improved.

Pseudocode:

```
function f(x, y):
if x mod size_of_zones == 0 or y mod size_of_zones == 0:
    return 0
elif x % (a number between the maximum and minimum block sizes, randomly picked but the same for each block) == 0:
    return 0
elif y % (a number between the maximum and minimum block sizes, randomly picked but the same for each block) == 0:
    return 0
else:
    return 1
```

My code for `a number between the maximum and minimum block sizes, randomly picked but the same for each block` was this:

```
shuffled_list_of_integers_between_min_and_max_block_sizes[(y floordiv zone_size) mod maximum_block_size]
```

for `x` and

```
shuffled_list_of_integers_between_min_and_max_block_sizes[(x floordiv zone_size) mod maximum_block_size]
```

for `y`.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question: it depends how 'naturally' you want it.
You can easily  use a random generator to generate some roads of a specific length; or better, make a road, then from both ends start a new road etc.

In case of a more natural way, think about how a real town/city looks like: longer roads, with smaller roads inside. this of course has to be reflected in the algorithm.

I don't understand your second question, ... just changing each # by different kind of symbols (denoting different buildings)? In that case, take into account buildings of different sizes. You better do the street layout first, then the remainding (maybe even by following the streets left/right side), filling in the buildings.

Edit:

You also could use instead of an 'ASCII' map like above use pointers to objects.
E.g. in the 14x14 map above instead of using one ASCII character, use an object pointer. Which can point to anything like:
- Road
- Building (inheriting from multiple building types)

You can have multiple squares point to the same object (denoting bigger buildings), or the same street.
Advantages:
- You can use all kind of properties (like what kind of building, functions of the building, age, statistics per building)
- For roads: name, pointers to other roads connected to it (for navigation purposes).

Comment: For the second question - have different types of building. Instead of 2 types of tile - empty and full, having many, where one tile is used to create streets, and the others are a random mix.

Comment: I assume # represents a building ... just use different symbols in that case ... and possibly special combinations for larger buildings (e.g. # = house, $01 = house (3 spaces), $002 = parking garage, four lines of $00004 for a 4x6 space such as an airport etc).

Comment: Also see edit in my answer for another solution for buildings.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean displaying, I meant "how would I write a function of the x and y of a tile, that decides what it is (including random distribution)?", although I guess that I could probably use something like Perlin noise, or a random function with two arguments.

Comment: Sorry, I never heard of Perlin noise, but I"m not a mathematician.